# I'm trying to understand an equality

Tags: calculus

Why is the following equality true?

$${log\left( {\frac{{{a^{\frac{1}{x}}} + {b^{\frac{1}{x}}}}}{2}} \right)^x} = \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{{{a^{\frac{1}{x}}} + {b^{\frac{1}{x}}}}}{2}} \right)}}{{1/x}}$$

Comment: It doesn't look true -- for example for $x=1$, $a=b=2$ it claims that $2=\log 2$ which is false.

Comment: Do you want a "$\log$" on the left hand side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{{\log \left( {\frac{{{a^{\frac{1}{x}}} + {b^{\frac{1}{x}}}}}{2}} \right)}}{{1/x}}=x \log \left( {\frac{{{a^{\frac{1}{x}}} + {b^{\frac{1}{x}}}}}{2}} \right) = {\log \left( {\frac{{{a^{\frac{1}{x}}} + {b^{\frac{1}{x}}}}}{2}} \right)}^x$$

Your equality is not correct - the right hand side is the logarithm of the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't, take $a=b=x=1$, then the left-hand-side is $1$, while the right-hand-side is $0$.